# How do I iterate through DOM elements in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have an XML file loaded into a DOM document, 
I wish to iterate through all 'foo' tags, getting values from every tag below it. I know I can get values via

```
$element = $dom->getElementsByTagName('foo')->item(0);
foreach($element->childNodes as $node){
    $data[$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

However, what I'm trying to do, is from an XML like,

```
<stuff>
  <foo>
    <bar></bar>
      <value/>
    <pub></pub>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar></bar>
    <pub></pub>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar></bar>
    <pub></pub>
  </foo>
  </stuff>
```

iterate over every *foo* tag, and get specific *bar* or *pub*, and get values from there.
Now, how do I iterate over *foo* so that I can still access specific child nodes by name?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Not tested, but what about:

```
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('foo');
$data = array();
foreach($elements as $node){
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $data[] = array($child->nodeName => $child->nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for $elementCount. Just append to $data like this: $data[] = array($child->nodeName => $child->nodeValue);

Comment: That did the trick! I was thinking too complicated. Must be tired.

Comment: Updated the code based on comment from troelskn, is that what you meant?

Comment: @Rory: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

It's generally much better to use XPath to query a document than it is to write code that depends on knowledge of the document's structure.  There are two reasons.  First, there's a lot less code to test and debug.  Second, if the document's structure changes it's a lot easier to change an XPath query than it is to change a bunch of code.

Of course, you have to learn XPath, but (most of) XPath isn't rocket science.

PHP's DOM uses the `xpath_eval` method to perform XPath queries.  It's documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xpath-eval.php), and the user notes include some pretty good examples.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another (lazy) way to do it.

```
$data[][$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score -2):

With [**FluidXML**](https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml) you can query and iterate XML very easly.

```
$data = [];

$store_child = function($i, $fooChild) use (&$data) {
    $data[] = [ $fooChild->nodeName => $fooChild->nodeValue ];
};

fluidxml($dom)->query('//foo/*')->each($store_child);
```

https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml