# Get the text content of a node, but ignore child nodes

Tags: php, domdocument

```
<foo>
  a
  <bar> b </bar>
</foo>
```

both `$foo->textContent` and `$foo->nodeValue` return `a b`.

How can I get just `a` (the text from the node, without text from any child nodes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `firstChild` :

```
$foo->firstChild->textContent;
```

Comment: What if there is text after `<bar>`? Will this get that text too?

Comment: No, but you'll be able to use `lastChild` instead. A better way to do this would be to wrap the text into an element.

Answer (score 9):

This might be helpful. Using what I found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191923/how-do-i-iterate-through-dom-elements-in-php)

```
$txt = "";
foreach($foo->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        $txt .= $node->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why it's so hard to find an actual answer to that simple question. After searching for hours, this answer IS the best answer found so far. Should be upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root><foo>a<bar>b</bar></foo><foo>bar</foo></root>');
$foos = $doc->getElementsByTagName('foo');
foreach($foos as $v){
   echo $v->firstChild->wholeText.'<br />';
}
```

The `firstChild` property of `DOMNode` returns a `DOMText` object as there is a "text node" before `<bar>` in first `<foo>`