# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser find numbers afte find

Tags: php, regex

i have code

```
$e = $html->find('span.item_color_title');
echo $e[3]->innertext;
```

this code good working give element

```
<span class="item_color_title">
                Minutes Played:
            </span>
```

but i want number after this element

```
<div class="item_float_left">
            <div class="section_title">
                ALL TIME STATS
            </div>
            <span class="item_color_title">
                Score:
            </span>
            518
            <br>
            <span class="item_color_title">
                Minutes Played:
            </span>
            305
            <br>
            <span class="item_color_title">
                Score per Minute:
            </span>
            1.7
            <br>
            <span class="item_color_title">
                Rank on Server:
            </span>
```

i need this 305 numbers after span only please help me

Comment: Witam Pana próbowałem już w ten sposób ale nie zwraca żadnej wartości ponieważ liczby nie są w elemencie prawdopodobnie

Comment: Please only use english. Not all users speak your native language. You can't go down to the actual element. You're going to need to be up one level, find the element, then take the next value. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697522/php-domdocument-get-text-after-tag might help you.

Comment: Yes, please use English here. Ok, try `preg_match('/<span\s+class="item_color_title">\s*Minutes Played:\s*<\/span>\s*\K\d+/', $text, $match)`, then `echo $match[0]`.

Comment: this good working thanks Ryszard udanej soboty

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for:

```
$page = "YOUR_HTML";

preg_match_all("/<span
class=\"item_color_title\">(\n*|.)*<\/span>(\n|\s|\d.\d)*/", $page,
$matches);

echo($matches[0][1]);
```