# XML node and childnode values to array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, child-nodes

I am trying to save node values to an array. This is the XML structure:

```
  <wildcards>
    <conference id="1">
      <seeds>
        <seed divId="1">10,7,17</seed>
        <seed divId="2">8,5,3</seed>
      </seeds>
      <wild>2,4</wild>
      <elimination>11,6,14,1,13,12,20,15</elimination>
    </conference>
 </wildcards>
```

[The xml file can be found here](http://www.tsn.ca/datafiles/XML/NHL/standings.xml) 
I want to associate the node values of conferences 1 with the array key being what place they are in the wildcard standings. Here is my code:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlDoc->load('http://www.tsn.ca/datafiles/XML/NHL/standings.xml'); 

$searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('wildcards');
foreach ($searchNode as $node) {
    $conference1 = $node->getElementsByTagName('conference');
    $conference1 = $conference1->item(0)->nodeValue;
}           

echo $conference1;
//  $conference1 = str_replace(" ",",",$conference1);
$conference1Array =  explode(',', $conference1);
$conference1ArrayLength = count($conference1Array) ;

for ($i = 1; $i < $conference1ArrayLength; $i++) {
    echo $i.": ".$conference1Array[$i-1];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

[If you go to this website](http://sjsharktank.com/standings2.php), you can see my current output. I tried to string replace whitespace and explode on ',' to get the array correct, but it did not work.

The output of conference1 is: `10,7,17 8,5,3 2,4 11,6,14,1,13,12,20,15`. Even though there is whitespace the replace did not work.

I need to have a comma after 17, 3 and 4. The idea is to insert the key for the team id into a column in my database named `seed`. I can then use PHP to determine what numbers are associated with each division / wildcard for table output. Here is what I mean by the association of the key and the team id / node values: 
Team Id: 10 -> 1   (first in division 1) 
Team Id: 7 -> 2    (second in division 1)
Team Id: 17 -> 3   (third in division 1)
Team Id: 8 -> 4    (1st in division 2)
Team Id: 5 -> 5    (2nd in division 2)
Team Id: 3 -> 6    (3rd in division 3)
Team Id: 2 -> 7    (Wildcard 1)
Team Id: 4 -> 8    (Wildcard 2)
Team Id: all the rest (eliminated)

I tried to get node values separately using [code from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191923/how-do-i-iterate-through-dom-elements-in-php), but I could not figure out how to get it to work with my situation. I don't have my attempted code for that anymore, by the way.

**Edit: I have looked at the links provided and have come up with this:**

```
$searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('wildcards');
$divData = array();
foreach($searchNode as $node){
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        foreach($child->childNodes as $secondChild) {
            foreach($secondChild->childNodes as $thirdChild) {
                $divData[] = array($thirdChild->nodeName => $thirdChild->nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This is my new output](http://sjsharktank.com/standings2.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output of conference1 is: 10,7,17 8,5,3 2,4 11,6,14,1,13,12,20,15. Even though there is whitespace the replace did not work.

You are almost there, use the following code to insert commas:

```
$conference1 = '10,7,17 8,5,3 2,4 11,6,14,1,13,12,20,15 ';
$conference1 = str_replace(" ",",",trim($conference1));
```

**UPDATE 1**

Try this to replace any characters tha are not comma or `[0-9]`

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]+/u', ",", $your_string);
```

**UPDATE 2**

To fix extra commas at begin and end, do another trim `$new_string = trim($your_string,",");`

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. My post explicitly states this (and I even have that line of code commented out). I tried it with `trim` as well. I am guessing the white space is not recognized because between numbers such as 17 and 8, there is a change in nodes.

Comment: With `trim` this is the output `10,7,17 ,,,,,,,,,,,,8,5,3 ,,,,,,,,, ,,,,,,,,,2,4 ,,,,,,,,,11,6,14,1,13,12,20,15`

Comment: I would need something to limit the commas. With regex, this is the output `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,10,7,17,,,,,,,,,,,,,8,5,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2,4,,,,,,,,,,11,6,14,1,13,12,20,15,,,,,,,`

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/[^0-9,]+/u', ",", trim($your_string));`

Comment: Now it is close. `,10,7,17,8,5,3,2,4,11,6,14,1,13,12,20,15,` just need the first and last comma gone. I can figure that one out on my own. Thanks for the answer. I will mark this correct.

Comment: One more question: will the regex break when the numbers go from `10,7,17` to `10,7,1`  ?? In other words, does the regex depend on the number of characters in the string?

Comment: No. The regex only targets strings other than numbers and commas. Answer updated.

Comment: http://sjsharktank.com/standings2.php    =) I will turn these numbers into tables tomorrow. Thanks for the help!