# How can I get a DOMElement's innerText in PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom

We use a CMS on our site. Many users have added HTML content into the database that is formatted weirdly. For example, putting all their HTML on a single line:

```
<h1>This is my title</h1><p>First paragraph</p><p>Second paragraph</p>
```

This renders in the browser correctly, of course. However, I am writing a script in PHP that loads up this data into a DOMDocument like so:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($row['body_html']);
var_dump($doc->documentElement->textContent);
```

This shows up as:

```
This is my titleFirst paragraphSecond paragraph
```

How can I get `documentElement` to return `innerText`, rather than `textContent`? I believe `innerText` will return a string with line breaks.

Comment: You should iterate over all elements in the DomDocument and get the text item by item and insert the whitespaces manually. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191923/how-do-i-iterate-through-dom-elements-in-php) for example. DomDocument itself can not know where it should but the whitespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cb0 said:

> You should iterate over all elements in the DomDocument and get the
>   text item by item and insert the whitespaces manually. Have a look
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191923/how-do-i-iterate-through-dom-elements-in-php) for example. DomDocument itself can not know where it should but
>   the whitespaces.

I wrote the following function to recursively traverse the DOMDocument object:

```
function get_text_from_dom($node, $text) {
  if (!is_null($node->childNodes)) {
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $node) {
      $text = get_text_from_dom($node, $text);
    }
  }
  else {
    return $text . $node->textContent . ' ';
  }
  return $text;
}
```

And replaced the code in the question with the following:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($row['body_html']);
var_dump(get_text_from_dom($doc->documentElement));
```

It is glorious.

Comment: Note that if there's a <script> tag, then textContent returns the actual contents (so does javascript). You may want to skip nodeName === "script" if you do not want to show script contents.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the nodevalue

```
 $arrDivs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div'); 

 foreach($arrDivs as $div){
     $text = $div->nodeValue;
     echo $text . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
 }
```